# Regression in MathNet gives different results from Excel

Tags: c#, excel, linear-regression, mathnet-numerics

I'm attempting to add a component that will do regression analysis on data in our application. I wrote a service that uses MathNet Numerics to perform a regression to compute coefficients for various characteristics. I'm testing it by passing it the same data as a regression analysis in Excel. The data I'm using is below in CSV format:

```
Accuracy,Age,Boundary Lines,Distance,Unit,County,Similarity,Size,Quality
0.894556528,0.301,1,1,1,1,0.753,0.76,0.625
0.870692849,0.234,1,0.737,1,1,0.598,0.804,0.625
1.044444444,0.49,1,1,1,0,0.714,0.933,0.833
1.04120514,0.165,1,1,1,1,0.224,0.268,0.833
1.157635468,0.179,1,1,1,1,0.224,0.268,0.8
1.080750408,1,1,1,1,1,0.826,0.536,0.833
1.100041511,1,1,1,1,1,0.569,0.5,0.833
0.932113964,1,1,1,1,1,0.78,0.25,0.625
0.966800438,0.267,1,1,1,1,0.916,0.408,0.625
0.941051136,0.212,1,0.713,1,1,0.755,0.667,0.625
0.932835821,0.429,1,1,1,1,1,0.999,1
1.689189189,0.12,1,1,1,1,1,0.941,1
1.199451679,0.292,1,1,1,1,1,0.6,1
0.7,0.188,1,0.981,1,1,1,1,0.333
0.795454545,1,1,1,1,1,1,0.364,0.5
```

"Accuracy" is the dependent value, and I'm calculating coefficients for the other columns using them as independent values. When I do a Regression in Excel, I get these results:

[image]

When I test my data in code, I get the same values except for the Boundary Lines and Unit coefficients, **while those are 0 in Excel, in my code they are -0.581 and 0.876, respectively**.

I'm doing the calculations by creating a Matrix of the ratings columns and a Vector of the Accuracy column and using `DirectRegressionMethod.NormalEquations`.

```
Matrix<double> ratingsMatrix = DenseMatrix.OfRowVectors(ratingsVectors);
Vector<double> accuracyVector = DenseVector.OfEnumerable(accuracyRatings);
Vector<double> coefficientVector = MultipleRegression.DirectMethod(ratingsMatrix, accuracyVector, DirectRegressionMethod.NormalEquations);
```

I'm trying to figure out the reason for the difference. The results from Excel worked well for what I needed them for, so I'd like to be able to duplicate it. I suspect it could be from the fact that both of those columns are all 1s?

Comment: Try changing format of answer in excel to show more decimal places.  Excel cells default to General Format that does a lot of funny things.  I believe the result you are getting from c# are accurate and do not believe the Excel results.